# Sprintf inserting NULL into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, printf

Good morning, desperately trying to resolve an issue I have with inserting blank date values into MySQL 5.7.19 and after 3 days turned here for help.

The DB is set to allow NULL - default NULL with the front end field sometimes being populated, more often not so null value.

The error pops up:

> *Cannot execute SQL statement: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'signedupdate' at row 1*

**Insert**

```
$lastInsertId = $this->GetConnection()->GetLastInsertId();
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_lead (client_id, signedupdate, plan_type) VALUES(%d, '%s', '%s');", $lastInsertId, $rowData['signedupdate'], $rowData['plan_type']);
$this->GetConnection()->ExecSQL($sql);
```

**Update**

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE tbl_lead SET signedupdate = '%s', plan_type = '%s'WHERE client_id = %d;", $rowData['signedupdate'], $rowData['plan_type']);
$this->GetConnection()->ExecSQL($sql);
```

Can anyone see where I may be going wrong?

Comment: I encourage you to use prepared statements instead to prevent from sql injection.

Comment: What's the ouput of `var_dump($lastInsertId, $rowData['signedupdate'], $rowData['plan_type'])`?

Comment: Test each of the parameters you are passing, %s will expect a string type, try adding tests before the sprintf using is_string to verify they are of the correct type.

Comment: if you don't want to insert a value for a field, and it has a default value (even NULL) just skip it in the insert statement. Do not pass '' that is a value (blank but still a value) and will be evaluated against the data type for that field: if it is a date it will fail

Answer (score 0):

Try to **echo** the query string before executing it and copy/paste that echoed query in phymyadmin and check for errors in the query

```
$lastInsertId = $this->GetConnection()->GetLastInsertId();
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_lead (client_id, signedupdate, plan_type) VALUES(%d, '%s', '%s');", $lastInsertId, $rowData['signedupdate'], $rowData['plan_type']);
echo $sql;

$this->GetConnection()->ExecSQL($sql);
```

Comment: I ran this in phpmyadmin and received the below error. So it appears '' is not accepted but NULL is and 0000-01-01 is accepted.</br> I really need it as NULL to avoid an reporting issues at a later stage but cant quite grasp why php is inserting as a string?<br/>

'**INSERT INTO tbl_lead (client_id, signedupdate, plan_type) VALUES(20943, '', '');{"success":false,"message":"Cannot execute SQL statement: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'signedupdate' at row 1","messageDisplayTime":0}**'

Answer (score 0):

In SQL (as in PHP) there's a big difference between the `NULL` value and a regular text variable that happens to have the letters N-U-L-L. This is handled automatically by any decent database library as long as the source variable is an actual `null` (rather than the text `'null`') and you use the library as intended.

You're using a custom custom database library so it's hard to say which case it is. If the library is not too bad it should provide a syntax like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_lead (client_id, signedupdate, plan_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
$this->GetConnection()->ExecSQL($sql, [
    $lastInsertId,
    $rowData['signedupdate'],
    $rowData['plan_type']
]);
```

Of course, not necessarily *this* syntax. Please refer to the library documentation of check its source code.

If it's a bad library it'll only provide escaping functions. If those functions add the quotes automatically you might be lucky with something like:

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO tbl_lead (client_id, signedupdate, plan_type) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)',
    $this->GetConnection()->EscapeValue($lastInsertId),
    $this->GetConnection()->EscapeValue($rowData['signedupdate']),
    $this->GetConnection()->EscapeValue($rowData['plan_type'])
);
$this->GetConnection()->ExecSQL($sql);
```

Again, *I just made up the syntax*.

Otherwise, you'll have to handle everything by yourself:

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO tbl_lead (client_id, signedupdate, plan_type) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)',
    $lastInsertId===null ? 'NULL' : "'" . $this->GetConnection()->EscapeValue($lastInsertId) . "'",
    $rowData['signedupdate']===null ? 'NULL' : "'" . $this->GetConnection()->EscapeValue($rowData['signedupdate']) . "'",
    rowData['plan_type']===null ? 'NULL' : "'" . $this->GetConnection()->EscapeValue($rowData['plan_type']) . "'"
);
$this->GetConnection()->ExecSQL($sql);
```

If the library doesn't even provide escape functions you should really stop here and switch to e.g. PDO. It might even be a good idea to switch anyway—in my experience, StrangelyCasedLibraries() tend to be of dubious quality.